# HDMI splitter: Plugging in second HDMI turns things blank

Tags: hdmi

I have a Renkforce HDMI splitter connected to my Predator 17 Windows laptop. My goal is to show the (Lenovo) VR device to both the headset screens as well as an external monitor (the external monitor is needed as my laptop monitor is broken, and too small anyway). When I plug in the external monitor into the HDMI splitter it all works, but as soon as I then also plug in the headset, the main monitor goes black and displays "no signal" after a while. What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: I am guessing that the Renkforce splitter does not support HDCP (content protection). Therefore the laptop can only connect with one display at a time. You will need a splitter that supports HDCP.

Comment: "WILL NOT BYPASS HDCP SIGNAL" says https://www.amazon.com/SOWTECH-Splitter-Version-Powered-Duplicated/dp/B01CCMOMM0 which seems to validate the response of BobtheMagicMoose - IF you are displaying HDCP-protected content. Are you?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was intentional content protection going on, as I'm simply streaming my screen (whatever SteamVR/ Windows Mixed Reality software is running, in this case it was only Windows Mixed Reality Home), but it wouldn't be the first time that borked copy protection shoots innocent casualties. Thanks!